# Finding out comm port settings of a running app

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, serial-port

The situation is as follows: I have a piece of hardware connected to a, windows running, PC via a serial port. This custom hardware is used to interface other hardware through GPIB. Now, the software that is used to operate this setup on the PC side needs to be changed without touching the hardware in the middle. The problem is getting a hold of the proper serial comm. parameters used for communication - setting them (the timeouts in particular - baud rates and bits are fine) to arbitrary values in the new software leads to a lot of comm errors so I'd like to know them precisely. The function GetCommTimeouts() would do the job, however you need the handle to the comm. device aquired via call to CreateFile() - only the original software has access to it. So the question is if one can get a hold of these settings from outside of the running, old app?

Thanks,
drinker

Comment: I would recommend using a tool like SysInternals' Process Monitor. You can monitor the calls that open and configure the serial port in the application.

Comment: That seems promising so I took a look at this utility. I was looking for CreateFile operations but that doesn't seem to carry useful information. What should I be looking for?

Comment: I guess I would need to catch calls to SetCommTimeouts - is it possible in the Proc Monitor?

Comment: Ok. I got it to work. I decompiled the sucker with IDA and it turns out the old program was build using national instruments' CVI so there was only a call to SetComTime and not winapis' SetCommTimeouts (SetComTime perhaps calls it internally). From the values pushed on the stack I managed to deduce the timeout parameters. Thanks for the help @R.Beiboer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a tool like [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx). This tool can monitor the calls that are used to open and configure a serial port.